# How to push from specific Remote and branch A to remote and branch B with terminal Git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I want to push from (**MyBranchA** and **MyRemoteA**) to (**MyBranchB** and **MyRemoteB**)
in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this taking advantage of the [Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) and a bit of syntax:

`git push MyRemoteB refs/remotes/MyRemoteA/MyBranchA:refs/heads/MyRemoteB/MyBranchB`